# What is the classical piano song from Ep 13 08:39 of parasyte?

Tags: music, parasyte

I've tried so hard to find this song and am drawing a blank. It's killing me. I thought it may have been Beethoven but I'm not sure. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Ave Maria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bosouX_d8Y) to me —  not quite Schubert's version, though, I think.

It sounds more like [Charles Gounod's version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNxz_sUEHLc), which apparently was composed to be superimposed with [Bach's Prelude No. 1 in C major, BWV 846](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iC7oxzU3Vc8) — so it may only be the Prelude itself?

Comment: Upon first listen, I assumed it was the Bach prelude, since I only heard the keyboard part. Apparently the voice in Gounod "Ave Maria" doesn't come in until a bit afterwards, though, so the music still matches up.